# Black Hole - Between event horizon and singularity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

Dear Physics Board Users

What is between the singularity and the event horizon? If the gravitation gets bigger and bigger coming nearer to a black hole, is then the gravition inside even bigger that the time, after special relativity, runs backward (speed higher c)? Is there something like 'room' or 'matter' there?

I'm not looking for a complete answer (would be great if, Mr. next nobel prize winner). I'm just looking for the momentary point of view about this hole in the spacetime and the newest scientific knowledge about it.

Thanks for sources and answers.

Comment: Here's one source for you on the many solutions to Einstein's equations.  http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/04/100409-black-holes-alternate-universe-multiverse-einstein-wormholes/

Comment: It's interesting to say that in a black hole exists an other universe. Like a raindrop falling out of our spacetime. So the hawking radiation would cause our universe to loose energy, so the energy would not be necessairly conserved in our universe, what this would lead to. Anyway thanks for the link

Comment: I tend to think that any so call universe created would not be very energetic as I can't see how there could be any more energy/matter in it than had already fallen in. In my opinion any spacetime inside could not grow faster than light which would limit it's size.

Comment: If the space inside is expanding with lightspeed (also when it's because massless not fixed to that), then you can't reach the border. The fact that you have less energy in it makes it on one side hard to understand but since we just don't know how it acutally is it's also plausible that with different cosmic constants the universe could act the same as ours. Your measurements depend always on the instruments. So if everything has half the mass you would not register (the definition of room and time may differ but this is also manmade)